# Consider $\{a+b \sqrt[3]2+c (\sqrt[3]{2})^2:a,b,c ∈\Bbb{Q}\}$. Show that this set is a field

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Am I supposed to check the property one by one, especially the multiplicative inverse?

Comment: You are probably supposed to check all the properties, yes. But most of the properties follow easily because this is a subset of $\Bbb{R}$. And I would say that the inverse property is the most important (since that is what makes it a field).

Comment: It's also worth verifying that $+$ and $\times$ are well-defined on this set, i.e. summing or producting two elements of this set produces another element of the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set is clearly closed under sums and products. To see it is closed under multiplicative inverse, use the fact that $p(x) = a + bx+ cx^2$ and $q(x) = x^3-2$ have no common factors, so that there are polynomials $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ so that $ap+bq = 1$ (this is the Euclidean algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not intended that you check the properties one by one. As you noticed, the multiplicative inverse could be really complicated to check (although possible).

Instead, try to verify it like this:

First construct a homomorphism $f$ from the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ to $\mathbb{R}$, sending $X$ to $\sqrt[3]{2}$.

Then show that the image of $f$ is exactly the set in question.

Finally, show that the kernel of $f$ contains the principal ideal generated by the polynomial $P=X^3 - 2$, and conclude by noting that $P$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.